# Unit tests can't find monodevelop classes after Unity upgrade

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I have just recently updated my Unity application and am having some issues porting over (any of) my unit tests. It seems like none of my general class objects (from Assembly-CSharp) are available in these tests. I have tried numerous things and after searching online I have yet to find anything. Here is my setup...

Here is my Asset folder structure. I added the "Editor" folder and "GivenA" test via the test runner.

[image]

Here is how things look in VS.

[image]

And here are the Tests.asmdef file settings

[image]

All of this worked perfectly previous to my Unity update, any help would be GREATLY appreciated. If more info is needed, I can supply that as well. Thanks!

All I am trying to do at this point is include this code with the GivenAControllerHealth.cs file:

```
var controllerHealth = new ControllerHealth();
```

I get the error 'The type of namespace 'ControllerHealth' could not be found.'

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution but if anyone has a helpful explanation (though I think it's probably just a general lack of Unity testing knowledge), I'd really appreciate it.

My method for adding test was via the Test Runner in the Play tab. Apparently none of these MonoDevelop objects are available at this point? I have seen mention of using Selenium for play tests and I have to assume it treats it like the items aren't available except through a Find->GetComponent fashion. Anyway, I just manually added an 'Editor' folder and imported my tests and they work perfectly. Looks like this defaulted everything to the 'Edit' tab in Test Runner, so that must be the key.

*In 'Play' mode, you have the option to **'Create PlayMode Test Assembly Folder'***

[image]

*Which doesn't work in my true 'unit' / 'functionality' tests*

[image]

*So I manually added the 'Editor' folder, which defaulted the tests to 'Edit' mode*

[image]

*Now everything runs smoothly, life is good again and I can move on with coding. :)*

[image]

Hopefully this isn't incoherent babble and it helps someone that runs into the issue later!